# How to Refresh Longlist Selector?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

This is my xaml code

```
<Grid>
                        <phone:LongListSelector Name="iList"  ItemsSource="{Binding}" Grid.Row="1">
                            <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>

                                    <StackPanel Height="60">
                                        <Grid Height="50">

                                            <TextBlock 
                                                Grid.Column="0"
                                                TextWrapping="NoWrap"
                                                Text="{Binding Mail}"
                                                Foreground="Black"
                                                FontSize="25"
                                                Margin="0,0,43,10"/>
                                            <Button  Visibility="{Binding BtnVisible}"  Margin="411,-16,-21,2" BorderBrush="Transparent" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}">
                                                <Button.Background>
                                                    <ImageBrush  Stretch="Uniform" ImageSource="/Assets/Icons/InvitePlusIcon.png"/>
                                                </Button.Background>
                                            </Button>
                                            <CheckBox Content="CheckBox"
                                                   IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked,Mode=TwoWay}"
                                                   Visibility="{Binding CBVisible}"
                                                   Background="SkyBlue"
                                                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                                   Margin="400,-13,0,-4"
                                                   VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="67" Width="53"/>

                                            <Border BorderBrush="#FFE0E0E0" BorderThickness="0 0 0 1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="456" />

                                        </Grid>

                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                        </phone:LongListSelector>

                    </Grid>
```

[1] When I click Edit application bar button. I need page refresh and my checkbox visible is true and button visible is false

[2]How to refresh the longlist selector?

[3]how to change dynamic control display?

[4]check my xaml code. Is this correct or not?

[5]anyone hellp me?

Comment: Post your C# code also. And no need to refresh the page. If you use `ObservableCollection` the items automatically get changed.

Comment: How? Did you use observables or other solution??

Comment: no I am using LonglistMulti selector